# What makes VS11 beta so fast?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a huge code-gen'd EDMX and the designer opened in about 2 seconds compared to >30 in VS2010. The whole thing is much snappier in every respect and it's a VM with only 2GB ram (although the hyper-v server is pretty powerful and i'm the only one using it now).

Is this the next generation gui framework? Is it WPF?  Am I seeing something new that makes it fast?

Comment: Many users thought that [Visual Studio could use some performance improvements](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2030253-improve-the-performance-of-visual-studio), so a large number of people on the Visual Studio team spent a lot of time making performance optimizations.

Comment: i never bothered to complain because i never saw an alternative but i sure appreciate it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot has been done to improve VS performance. Their blog has a series of posts that explain in more detail:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/05/visual-studio-11-beta-performance-part-1.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/12/visual-studio-11-beta-performance-part-2.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/19/visual-studio-11-beta-performance-part-3.aspx

They don't mention EDMX files specifically, but it probably has to do with improvements with loading solution files (part 2).

Comment: thank you, i hope you don't lose the points if another close vote comes through because this was useful to me (so i'm assuming it would be to others)

Answer (score 0):

Probably by not doing as much at startup.
If you skip reading the browse info file until it's needed or only parse files as they are edited rather than at startup you can improve the apparent performance a lot.